# (slightly buggy) mobile website vs. desktop website

Tags: website-design, mobile, mobile-web

I have a [website](http://creativeSOG.com/) which has a desktop and a mobile version for phones. 
Now, the mobile version is slightly buggy but does still work. The images are in the wrong places and partly even overlapping.

How acceptable is it to release a less-than-perfect product? Is it better to remove the mobile version or leave it as-is?

Answer (score 1):

It's not uncommon to release a less than perfect product as long as you plan on fixing the bugs you know about and thoroughly test it.

Ensure that these bugs don't hinder the user or they will simply navigate away from your website. If your images are in the wrong place and create issues for navigation then that could be worse than not having a mobile website.

If your desktop site is working with fewer bugs then make sure you give your mobile user a clear path to switch between modes. Just don't force them down the route of switching to desktop.